# Dynamics crm opening assign window

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

In a javascript function, I want to open the window that is usually opened when the user clicks on the "Assign" button in the lead form.

In the ribbon workbench, I see that the function that is called on the click of Assign is `XrmCore.Commands.Assign.assignObjectLegacy`, in the library `Main_system_library.js`.

Is it possible to call this function in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing such things like using internal libraries, calling internal methods are **unsupported** in Dynamics CRM. Future version of product changes may affect this implementation.

Instead, try to use jQuery to find the button element & invoke the `onclick` event like `$('#assignbuttonid').click()`. This is too unsupported because we cannot use DOM manipulation but somewhat ok.

Otherwise I don’t see any alternate supported solution to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery is one way to mimic the feature but like Arun said it's unsupported and risk to break in the next update. Instead, I would call a custom action. An action is basically a workflow. You can assign your entity via javascript and it will be supported.

Here is a sample you can use: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/nishantranaweblog/archive/2017/05/27/sample-code-to-call-action-using-web-api-in-crm